Azure AI. Failed to connect data. Could not 'MergeOrUpload' document to the search index
I'm trying to add data from Blob storage to Azure Open AI Studio.

After launching and preparing a small number of files, an error occurs:
Could not 'MergeOrUpload' document to the search index
There are 7000 files in the storage.
How can I fix this error?
I am try to reload Azure AI Studio

You can see the reasons here for the error you got.
The possible reasons are below.

Trouble connecting to the target index (that persists after retries) because the service is under other load, such as querying or indexing.
Document is too large to be indexed.
Document contains too many objects in a collection.

You mentioned having 7000 files; there's a possibility that the search service will be under overload, so scale up your search service.
Also, check whether the document contains too many objects; at most, '3000' objects are allowed to be in collections across the entire document.
If the document is too large, check this document on how to index such large documents.

@Dmitriy Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
